# KMM Gradle how to process tasks "Task :shared:linkPodDebugFramework.." in parallel

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform

i have problem with KMM build performance. Almost whole build takes seconds except shared part with takes up to 8minutes on M1 and more than 20minutes on older i7. Almost whole process uses all cores except last tasks - linkPod*FrameworkIosArm64, linkPod*FrameworkIosX64, linkPod*FrameworkIosFat, linkPod*FrameworkIosSimulatorArm64. They use only one core and run one at the time.
Is it possible to setup Gradle to process that tasks in parallel?

Here is my build.gradle.kts and gradle.properties.

```
#Gradle
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options\="-Xmx2048M" -XX:+UseParallelGC
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true

#Kotlin
kotlin.code.style=official

#Android
android.useAndroidX=true
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
android.enableJetifier=true

#MPP
kotlin.mpp.enableCInteropCommonization=true
kotlin.mpp.androidSourceSetLayoutVersion=2
kotlin.native.binary.objcExportSuspendFunctionLaunchThreadRestriction=none
```

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("io.realm.kotlin") version "1.10.0"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.0"
}

kotlin {
    android {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }

    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Shared Module"
        homepage = „shared module.cz"
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    val ktorVersion = "2.3.0"
    
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
                implementation("io.github.aakira:napier:2.6.1")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.realm.kotlin:library-base:1.10.1")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.3.3")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }

        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "cz.exmple.app.shared"
    compileSdk = 33
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 33
    }
}
```

I tried to change gradle.properties and added

```
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

But improvements are minimal.